# Laptop fan control through Embedded Controller or ACPI

Tags: windows, driver, acpi, dsdt

I've been trying to control the fan of my Lenovo Yoga 910-13IKB laptop (Windows 10) to avoid thermal throttling (I already undervolted the CPU and GPU). To achieve this I need to find a way of modifying the specific registers that control the fan on my laptop's embedded controller.

Using `RWEverything` I opened all the ACPI tables on my computer, after extracting the DSDT table I found nothing but 1 register that seemed related to the fan, "CFAN" it is 1 bit long and changing it doesn't have any effect. Seems to be off by default.

[DSDT.txt](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/files/5067575/DSDT.txt)

After this i started investigating and got into one of the SSDTs where i found this:

```asl
Name(OSD1, Package(21)
{
  0x04, "CPU Fan Duty Cycle", "RAW", 0x04, "CPU Fan #1 Speed", "RPM",
  0x03, "Skin Temp 0", "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 1 ", "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 2 ",
  "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 3 ", "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 4 ", "RAW"
})
Name(OSD2, Package(24)
{
  0x04, "CPU Fan Duty Cycle", "RAW", 0x04, "CPU Fan #1 Speed", "RPM",
  0x03, "Skin Temp 0", "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 1 ", "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 2 ",
  "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 3 ", "RAW", 0x03, "Thermistor 4 ", "RAW",
  0x03, "Thermistor 5 ", "RAW"
})
```

and a couple lines after i found this:

```asl
Method(OSDD, 0, Serialized)
{
    If(LEqual(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECAV, One))
    {
        If(LEqual(TSDB, One))
        {
            Name(OSD2, Package(8)
            {
                0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000,
                0x80000000, 0x80000000
            })
            Store(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.PENV)), Index(OSD2, Zero))
            Store(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.CFSP)), Index(OSD2, One))
            Store(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TSR3)), Index(OSD2, 0x02))
            Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER1)), 0x02), Index(OSD2, 0x03))
            Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER2)), 0x02), Index(OSD2, 0x04))
            Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER3)), 0x02), Index(OSD2, 0x05))
            Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER4)), 0x02), Index(OSD2, 0x06))
            Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER5)), 0x02), Index(OSD2, 0x07))
            Return(OSD2)
        }
        Name(OSD1, Package(7)
        {
            0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000, 0x80000000,
            0x80000000
        })
        Store(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.PENV)), Index(OSD1, Zero))
        Store(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.CFSP)), Index(OSD1, One))
        Store(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TSR3)), Index(OSD1, 0x02))
        Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER1)), 0x02), Index(OSD1, 0x03))
        Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER2)), 0x02), Index(OSD1, 0x04))
        Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER3)), 0x02), Index(OSD1, 0x05))
        Store(ShiftLeft(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.ECRD(RefOf(\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.TER4)), 0x02), Index(OSD1, 0x06))
        Return(OSD1)
    }
    Return(Package(0){})
}
```

[SSDT.txt](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/files/5067576/SSDT.txt)

As you can see, it seems that the fan duty cycle is register `\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.PENV` and the fan speed is `\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.CFSP`. However, I looked in every table for the words "PENV" and "CFSP" but couldn't find the numeric address. (No definition anywhere)

So, using `RWEverything` I was able to identify a couple of registers that changed in sync with the fan.

(Tried to post an image of the registers but didn't have enough reputation)

I tried modifying all of these registers with no luck.

Maybe there is another way to modify `\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.PENV` and `\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.H_EC.CFSP` through ACPI, or a thrid party driver for the Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Embedded Controller?

Feel free to ask any questions and any help will be greatly appreciated.